# How do I make a review ("pull") request in Git without waiting for approval before merge?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, pull-request

I would like a team member to review my code. However, in our team we do not delay merging until  code review., So, I might want to ask for review (a "pull request") immediately before merging to the shared branch ("*master*"). Also, I might forget to do that and  ask for review right  after merging.

Git pull requests seem to carry the assumption that you are waiting for the reviewer to pull your code into the shared branch.

What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Install a *hook* in your repository which sends the diff file by email to the reviewers any time you commit.

Comment: That could make sense. How would I do that? I am using Git on BitBucket.